# Database "on delete cascade" mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Anybody know if fluent NHibernate can be used to generate keys with "on delete cascade", when using XML mappings for NHibernate it is called "on-delete='cascade'".

Reason I want this is that the other end of my mapping holds a large blob so it would be convenient if it just "disappeared"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple:

```
HasMany(x => x.YourCollection).Inverse().ForeignKeyCascadeOnDelete();
```

Comment: Ahh I was looking in the wrong place (as I have a HasOne().Constrained()). I will accept this and rewrite my mapping with a collection of one...

Answer (score 1):

On the column,  use `Cascade.Delete()`, there's other options as well.

Comment: Just to be clear I don't want NHibernate to manage the cascade I want the database to do this. I am pretty sure that the solution you suggest will make Nhibernate do it...